# Different seeds lead to extremely different results with modified U-Net

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, image-segmentation, random-seed, unet-neural-network

I am using a modified U-Net architecture to perform auto-segmentation on a dataset of biomedical images. Although I have achieved some decent results, I have noticed that the training of the model is highly dependent on the seed that I set at the beginning.  Using the same seeds and performing multiple runs of my code with those seeds results in very repeatable results.  However, with the exact same code, hyperparameters, and training/test set images, the results vary wildly with different seeds.  My loss function is the dice coefficient loss (the primary outcome metric that I am concerned with is the dice coefficient) and with some seeds my loss will level off at about 0.95 and only go down around 0.01 over the course of many many epochs and with other seeds my loss won't start to level off until about 0.10.  The only difference is the seed.  Since the total range for dice coefficient loss is only 0-1 these values represent extremely different results.

As additional information, this phenomenon has occurred for different training set sizes ranging from a few hundred images to a few thousand images. I have double checked and do not believe there to be an issues with my data. Additionally, my dataset is highly unbalanced (only about 3% of my pixels are the region I am trying to segment).

Things I have already tried:

- Using alternative loss functions such as binary cross entropy, focal loss, tversky loss, and combined binary cross entropy and dice loss
- Adjusting hyperparameters: learning rate (I am using adam optimizer), batch size, filter sizes, model depth
- Trying different kernel initializers
- Different activations functions (relu vs leaky relu)
- Gradient clipping
- Batch normalization
- Dropout

Any suggestions of how I can solve this issue would be greatly appreciated.  This issue has stalled my progress significantly and as I add to my training set the issue seems to exacerbated further by causing me to have to test quite a few seed options before finding one that allows my model to train correctly.

Below is my code starting after I import my images and modules, crop the images and masks, and put them into arrays:

Please note that in my full code setting the seeds and hyperparameters goes at the top.

```
from numpy.random import seed
seed(3)
from tensorflow import set_random_seed
set_random_seed(4)

# Define Parameters
batch_size = 16
batch_size_test = 1
filter_size = 8
kernel_dimension = 5
learning_rate = 1e-4
num_epochs = 25

# these are functions for pairing the image to its respective mask
def get_dataset(images, mask, batch_size):
    dataset_input = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.constant(images, dtype=tf.float32)) #converts to tf type
    dataset_mask = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.constant(mask, dtype=tf.float32)) #converts to tf type

    dataset_input = dataset_input.map(lambda x: tf.image.per_image_standardization(x)) #standardizes the image
    dataset_input = dataset_input.map(lambda x: tf.image.adjust_contrast(x,1.2)) #adds some contrast

    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((dataset_input, dataset_mask)) #pairs the images to the masks into one tf array
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(len(images)).repeat() #randomly shuffles dataset and repeats the dataset
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size).prefetch(batch_size) # set the batch size
    print('image shape: ', dataset.output_shapes[0])
    print('label shape: ', dataset.output_shapes[1])
    print('types: ', dataset.output_types)
    print()
    print(dataset)
    return dataset

def get_dataset_noshuffle(images, mask, batch_size):
    dataset_input = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.constant(images, dtype=tf.float32))
    dataset_mask = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.constant(mask, dtype=tf.float32))

    dataset_input = dataset_input.map(lambda x: tf.image.per_image_standardization(x))
    dataset_input = dataset_input.map(lambda x: tf.image.adjust_contrast(x,1.2))

    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((dataset_input, dataset_mask))
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size).prefetch(batch_size)
    print('image shape: ', dataset.output_shapes[0])
    print('label shape: ', dataset.output_shapes[1])
    print('types: ', dataset.output_types)
    print()
    print(dataset)
    return dataset

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(images, mask, test_size=0.0001, random_state=42)
X_test = testimages # if you want to use a separate set of images that you imported earlier then use this
y_test = testmask # and this

# use the get_dataset function to pair the X_train with y_train and X_test with y_test. adjust batch size as needed
train_dataset = get_dataset(X_train, y_train, batch_size)
test_dataset = get_dataset(X_test, y_test, batch_size_test)
test_dataset_noshuffle = get_dataset_noshuffle(X_test, y_test, batch_size_test)


def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred):
    smooth = 1.
    y_true_f = tf.keras.backend.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = tf.keras.backend.flatten(y_pred)
    intersection = tf.keras.backend.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    return (2. * intersection + smooth) / (tf.keras.backend.sum(y_true_f) + tf.keras.backend.sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)

def dice_coef_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return 1. - dice_coef(y_true, y_pred)

def unet(pretrained_weights = None,input_size = (size,size,1), df=filter_size, kernel_size = kernel_dimension): 
    
    inputs = Input(input_size)
    
    
    conv1 = Conv2D(df, kernel_size, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(inputs)
    conv1 = BatchNormalization()(conv1)
    conv1 = Conv2D(df, kernel_size, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv1)
    conv1 = BatchNormalization()(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
    
    
    conv2 = Conv2D(df*2, kernel_size, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool1)
    conv2 = BatchNormalization()(conv2)
    conv2 = Conv2D(df*2, kernel_size, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv2)
    conv2 = BatchNormalization()(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)
    
    
    conv3 = Conv2D(df*2*2, kernel_size, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool2)
    conv3 = BatchNormalization()(conv3)
    conv3 = Conv2D(df*2*2, kernel_size, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv3)
    conv3 = BatchNormalization()(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)
    
    
    conv4 = Conv2D(df*2*2*2, kernel_size, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool3)
    conv4 = BatchNormalization()(conv4)
    conv4 = Conv2D(df*2*2*2, kernel_size, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv4)
    conv4 = BatchNormalization()(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv4)

    
    conv5 = Conv2D(df*2*2*2*2, kernel_size, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool4)
    conv5 = BatchNormalization()(conv5)
    conv5 = Conv2D(df*2*2*2*2, kernel_size, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv5)
    conv5 = BatchNormalization()(conv5)
    
    
    up6 = Conv2D(df*2*2*2, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv5))
    merge6 = concatenate([conv4,up6], axis = 3) 
    conv6 = Conv2D(df*2*2*2, kernel_size, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge6)
    conv6 = BatchNormalization()(conv6)
    conv6 = Conv2D(df*2*2*2, kernel_size, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv6)
    conv6 = BatchNormalization()(conv6)
    
    
    up7 = Conv2D(df*2*2, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv6))
    merge7 = concatenate([conv3,up7], axis = 3)
    conv7 = Conv2D(df*2*2, kernel_size, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge7)
    conv7 = BatchNormalization()(conv7)
    conv7 = Conv2D(df*2*2, kernel_size, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv7)
    conv7 = BatchNormalization()(conv7)
    
    
    up8 = Conv2D(df*2, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv7))
    merge8 = concatenate([conv2,up8], axis = 3)
    conv8 = Conv2D(df*2, kernel_size, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge8)
    conv8 = BatchNormalization()(conv8)
    conv8 = Conv2D(df*2, kernel_size, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv8)
    conv8 = BatchNormalization()(conv8)
    
    
    up9 = Conv2D(df, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv8))
    merge9 = concatenate([conv1,up9], axis = 3)
    conv9 = Conv2D(df, kernel_size, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge9)
    conv9 = BatchNormalization()(conv9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(df, kernel_size, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv9)
    conv9 = BatchNormalization()(conv9)
    
    conv9 = Conv2D(2, kernel_size, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv9)
    conv10 = Conv2D(1, (1,1), activation = 'sigmoid')(conv9)

    model = Model(inputs, conv10)

    model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr = learning_rate), loss = dice_coef_loss, metrics = ['accuracy','binary_accuracy', 'mae',
                            tf.keras.metrics.Precision(name='precision'), dice_coef, jacard_coef,                
                            tf.keras.metrics.FalseNegatives(thresholds=0.5, name='FN', dtype=None),
                            tf.keras.metrics.FalsePositives(thresholds=0.5, name='FP', dtype=None),
                            tf.keras.metrics.TrueNegatives(thresholds=0.5, name='TN', dtype=None),
                            tf.keras.metrics.TruePositives(thresholds=0.5, name='TP', dtype=None)])
    
    model.summary() #if you want to printout all the parameters and model summary 

    if(pretrained_weights):
        model.load_weights(pretrained_weights)

    return model

model = unet(pretrained_weights=None, df=filter_size, input_size=(size, size, 1), kernel_size=kernel_dimension)

steps_epoch = np.int16(np.ceil(len(X_train)/batch_size)) # determines your steps per epoch
steps_val = np.int16(np.ceil(len(X_test)/batch_size_test)) # determines your steps for the test set

model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(weights_name, monitor='val_loss',verbose=1, save_best_only=True)

#This is the actual training part of the code
history = model.fit(train_dataset, validation_data=test_dataset, steps_per_epoch=steps_epoch, 
                    validation_steps=steps_val, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=num_epochs, verbose=1, callbacks=[model_checkpoint])
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is sometimes noticed when you do not have enough training data. Get more training data. If you cannot get additional data, you can increase the data through augmentation techniques. Generally with enough data points the model converges to a minima - if not stuck in local or saddle. Another approach is to use a pre-trained model and fine tune on it. As I see you are initializing the model from scratch -

```
model = unet(pretrained_weights=None, df=filter_size, input_size=(size, size, 1), kernel_size=kernel_dimension)
```

Comment: the fact that converges to a minima does not solve it's problem, he is experiencing local minima, which is usually fight using more data, a "more supervised" learning, pretraining, better initialization and so on... it's absolutely unlikely that your NN will converge to a global minima... your answer is mainly correct, but please fix those things

Comment: Hello @der Fotik and Alberto Sinigaglia.  Thank you both very much for your responses.  Alberto is correct, I am converging to a minima on each run; however, the minima achieved varies wildly based on the seed setting.  This is the issue.  Unfortunately, I have already tried to increase the data, as I mentioned in my post from a few hundred to several thousand training images.  The issue actually becomes more pronounced with more training data. Also, I have tried training for more epochs (far past when my model plateaus) and this has not fixed the issue either.

Comment: As for pre-training: my dataset is relatively large (for the task at hand compared to similar segmentation tasks in the literature), quite homogeneous, and very different from any publicly available datasets that have pre-trained models available.  Thus, I do not believe that using a pre-trained model makes sense in this case.  Please let me know if either of you disagree.

Comment: Finally, Alberto, do you have any suggestions for how I could accomplish "better initialization" (as I believe this may be very closely tied to my issue)? I have tried the following 3 kernel initialization methods as I had read they might help: glorot_uniform, glorot_normal, and he_normal.  These did not improve anything. Please let me know if there are other kernel initializers I should try that I missed, or if there are other avenues for improving my initialization in general.

Comment: I have been stuck on this issue for months and have read everything I could find related to my issue.  Please let me know if anyone has any other suggestions.

Comment: Two things: 
1. Since now you have mentioned there is very less data for the region you want to segment, can you try data augmentation? I do not see any augmentation code here.
2. How may test sample are you having?

Comment: @der Fotik I have not yet tried data augmentation.  Since this is a segmentation problem using data augmentation cannot increase the relative frequency of the small region I want to segment so I didn't think it would help to alleviate that issue.  However, due to your suggestion I will give it a try.  There are about 350 test images which equates to about 10% of my data (the other 90% is used for training).